# select single item from optgroup

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, optgroup

i want to select 4 items from select with single item from optgroup ..
i tried bootstrap select by silviomoreto [bootstrap-silviomoreto](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) but its not working as desired... 
i just want to do it using jquery not necessarily above plugin..

```html
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="4">
    <optgroup label="Group1" data-max-options="1">
      <option>Subject-1</option>
      <option>Subject-2</option>
      <option>Subject-3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group2" data-max-options="1">
      <option>Subject-1</option>
      <option>Subject-2</option>
      <option>Subject-3</option>
    </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Group3" data-max-options="1">
      <option>Subject-1</option>
      <option>Subject-2</option>
     </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Group5" data-max-options="1">
      <option>Subject-1</option>
      <option>Subject-2</option>
     </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Group6" data-max-options="1">
     <option>Subject-1</option>
      <option>Subject-2</option>
     </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: brijesh this is not what i want i want to limit total selection to 4 with one from each optgroup

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
$("option").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).siblings("option:selected").length) {
       $(this).siblings("option").attr("selected",false);
    }
    if($(this).closest("select").find("option:selected").length>4) {
       $(this).attr("selected",false);    
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/waxs26uy/1/)

Comment: i tried  follow ur way its not working .. may be i may doing something wrong.. where shld i actually place this code . $().ready or somewhere else..

Comment: thankx brijesh //that worked fine for me . how shld i get the values of selected items on click or once final selection (all four) are selected..